# Would Like to Upgrade CPU of hp pavilion touchsmart 11z-e000 Notebook

Tags: upgrade

I recently bought a HP TouchSmart 11Z-e000 Laptop but I am not happy with performae. It is using AMD A4 CPU with 4 GB RAM. I think the RAM is enough. Culprit here is CPU for the slow performance. I would like to upgrade this CPU to some higher version which is compatible to this laptop.
Could anyone point me what CPU are there in market to use with this notebook.

- [Product Information](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?cc=us&dlc=en&jumpid=hpr_r1002_inen_link4&lang=en&lc=en&product=5404789)
- [Review at LAPTOP tom's guide](http://www.laptopmag.com/reviews/laptops/hp-pavilion-touchsmart-11z)

Comment: While the processor is socketed (Socket FS1), AMD doesn't sell mobile CPUs at retail. I really don't think it's worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely trying to replace your CPU will destroy your laptop and/or simply not work.  You would only see a performance gain if you upgraded to the AMD A8 series.  This would be possible since they use the same socket, but your laptop couldn't handle the additional heat even if the BIOS would support the A8 (it likely does not.)

Answer (score 1):

This laptop can be customized to a more respectable 1.4GHz A6 processor (a quad-core chip with an improved graphics processor), 8GB of RAM and a 500GB HDD ($530). As functional as it is, the extreme measures taken to keep the cost down are painful to live with, at least on the tested model.

Comment: Is this a simple remove and replace of the CPU?